# odom frame, robot base link frame and local cost map are not in the same plane

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the ros navigation tutorial from omniverse isaac sim, and discovered that the odom, local costmap and robot base link are not in the same plane.
(I wanted to upload the screenshot of the rviz result and tf tree, but I lack of points..)

Sorry if this is the basic question and thanks for your advices in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409980/odom-frame,-robot-base-link-frame-and-local-cost-map-are-not-in-the-same-plane./) by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-29**:
Now you will be able to upload screenshot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kindly upload screenshot to elaborate well..want to help you out  l.

---

Originally posted by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) with karma: 96 on 2022-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-29**:
Hello,

This is not the answer; please use add a comment button to request a screenshot or any other chat.

**Comment by [mirakim](https://answers.ros.org/users/111543/mirakim/) on 2022-12-08**:
Thank you for your reply. I wanted to upload the screenshot but I needed more points to upload some image files.. By the way, I solved the problem. The issue was related to the initial pose of the robot, which was different to the position values in the launch file.

**Comment by [Davies Ogunsina](https://answers.ros.org/users/103873/davies-ogunsina/) on 2022-12-08**:
Okay ,great